# "list index out of range" on simple random loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, random

I typed in this simple while loop, but for some reason it sometimes givies me the list index out of range error. It is strange that it only sometimes gives me the error and the more "Dice" I add, the more likely it is to error. It appears on the `Dice_total = Dice_Total + (dice[random.randint(1,6)])` line

```
import random

Dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Dice_Count = int(input())
Dice_Total = 0

while Dice_Count > 0:
    Dice_Total = Dice_Total + (Dice[random.randint(1,6)])
    print (Dice_Total)
    Dice_Count = Dice_Count - 1

print(Dice_Total)
```

Comment: `Dice[6]` does not exist.

Comment: Why are you using a list for this, when you would get the correct output by using `random.randint(1, 6)` *directly*, without using those values as indices?

Comment: Well this is strange. I found it extremely hard and couldn't solve it before, now I see it so clearly. Even before I read the answers. well, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, the issue is you're calling the 7th index `Dice[6]` which is out of range.  Index on Python is 0 based, i.e. `Dice[0]` is the 1st item and `Dice[5]` is the 6th item (last).

What I don't understand is why bother defining Dice at all? If you updated the line

```
Dice_Total = Dice_Total + (Dice[random.randint(0,5)])
```

to

```
Dice_Total = Dice_Total + random.randint(1,6)
```

it would have the same effect, and you wouldn't run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

List indexes are zero-based, so you need to select a random value between 0 and 5 (inclusive), not 1 and 6:

```
Dice_Total = Dice_Total + (Dice[random.randint(0, 5)])
```

Comment: Or just use `Dice_Total = Dice_Total + random.randint(1, 6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that lists use zero-indexing. `Dice[1]` returns the **2<sup>nd</sup>** item in the list, not the first. Thus, `Dice[6]` would attempt to access the **7<sup>th</sup>** item, which does not exist.

Thus, your `random.randint(1, 6)` should be `random.randint(0, 5)`.

---

```
import random

Dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Dice_Count = int(input())
Dice_Total = 0

while Dice_Count > 0:
    Dice_Total = Dice_Total + (Dice[random.randint(0,5)])
    print (Dice_Total)
    Dice_Count = Dice_Count - 1

print(Dice_Total)
```